# How to implement validation in play framework

Tags: javascript, scala, validation, security, playframework

I'm using play framework 2 with scala. How can I implement user validation on scala template engine? I need something like captcha (I've heard that google recaptcha is a good choice) to validate that the user is a human not a bot.

As I said, I'm using play and thats why all my POST/GET functions are documented in routes file. So, if the user passes validation what method should I call? For example there is a form with field 'Name'. The user passes the validation and he calls something like

`POST /create/:name`

to call Scala some method for creating post. The problem is that everyone can call it just by url without passing the validation.

So as a solution I see two ways: to use javascript API to call Scala method or to pass some "validation token" that will be used as a key to check on server if user has passed validation or not. Can you tell me some general validation patterns used for frontend

Update:

I have tried Google's recaptcha, but I'm confused of using provided public-private keys, I want to generate them by myself. Thats why I want to look at other possible solutions of my problem.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you mean user *authentication*?

Comment: @YoungSpice generaly no. I dont want to implement user login feature. All I want is to check if user is a real human or no.

Comment: @cchantep please check my question, I've updated it

Comment: Do you use standard form validation as described in this article? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used recaptcha and it is okay. Later I will implement my own captcha mechanism.

Thanks, Sergei.